# React Native - is it recommended to use same session id for Signal API and Video Chat

Tags: reactjs, native, opentok

I'm working over Video chat + Text chat feature using Opentok React Native, where I'm in dilemma to use the same session for video chat and text chat

https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/

Can we have the same session or a separate session? also, how can we create an instance of the same session and reuse it for Publisher/Subscriber

Comment: Are you want to use video chat and text chat simultaneously or separately ???

Answer (score 0):

Manik here from TokBox.

Yes, you should use the same session if the participants are the same for chat and video. You can use the same `sessionId` and this would result in connecting to the same session.

Please note that the OpenTok React Native library creates a native session instance each time you mount the `OTSession` component. If you unmount the `OTSession` component and re-mount it, you will have a new session instance in the native layer because unmounting the component results in setting the native session instance to nil/null.

Comment: Thanks Manik, Let me give you more insight, My requirement is, all participants 
 (subscriber + publisher) needs to create meeting notes for video chat first and then in a separate view, they can have a discussion on video chat... So for meeting notes, I'm using "Signal" property which needs to pass as params in OTSession and in next view again I have to use  <OTSession> for video chat... is this a right approach? or can we reuse the first OTSession instance for video chat? please advise

Comment: @sachingupta Thanks for clarifying. If they are creating meeting notes first using signaling and move to a different view, will changing to the different view cause you to unmount and remount OTSession? If so, then you would have a new native instance, if you don't then you can reuse it. If you are using the same sessionId, you shouldn't have any issues really.

Comment: Sure, I tried with the same sessionId today, mostly its works but sometimes subscriber losing the audio, upon joining second or third time audio starts working, don't know what is happening. Can you please shed some light on this from prior experiences?
Also, When subscriber tries to join the session using the iOS device, it takes 10 - 20 sec of time before joining, but on iOS simulator, no delay at all... Could you also advise upon receiving black screen from Publisher, is there any inbuilt option/property which helps to show an image on subscriber view?

Comment: Can you tell how to add autofocus and get rid of pixelated video ?